# How can I select a specific column from the first table in a with relation in laravel?

Tags: mysql, database, laravel, eloquent

[image]

For example, I want to select id, title from books instead of *, is there a way to do that?

Comment: Check out the [`select`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#select-statements) method.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using a relation, try this:

```
$book->author()->get(['id', 'title']);
```

The above query give you the `id` and `title` of the `author`.

For simple queries, you can omit the relation:

```
$book->get(['id', 'title']);
```

This will return an array containing the `id` and `title` of the selected book.

Comment: I'm using laravel 5 repos, and what I need is to select columns from the first table not the second table, in a with relation

Answer (score 0):

Here is example:

```
$books = App\Book::select('id', 'title')->with('author')->get();
```